# Performing raster analysis using Arcpy - in_memory does not preserve raster shape

Tags: arcpy, raster, slope, in-memory

I am creating a script tool using Arcpy and it transforms elevation data into a final clip polygon as part of a lengthy site selection tool. When I perform the raster analysis and save my intermediate data to disc, it works fine; however, when saving the intermediate layers to in_memory, it does not preserve the shape of the output rasters. It forces them into a rectangle.

```
Slope_1 = "D:\egm722\Data\Scratch.gdb\\Slope_1" 
arcpy.gp.Slope_sa(Elevation_Data, Slope_1, "DEGREE", "1", "PLANAR", "METER")
```

[image: Saving to disc]

```
Slope_1 = "in_memory\\Slope_1"
arcpy.gp.Slope_sa(Elevation_Data, Slope_1, "DEGREE", "1", "PLANAR", "METER")
```

[image: Using in_memory]

How can I get the shape preserved using in_memory? This is only one process of the tool which contains many processes and I don't want my end user to have to save lots of intermediate data to disc.

Comment: Are you sure you are not just displaying no-data as black in the second screenshot and no-data as transparent in the first? (Layer Properties - Symbology - Display NoData as)

Comment: Yes, because my final analysis includes the black area, which happens to be the Irish Sea. Too wet for a final site. Saving to disc my final analysis is correct.

Comment: If this [post](https://community.esri.com/ideas/9260) is still valid, no data will be changed to -999 when using in_memory. Try using [Set Null](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/setting-cell-values-to-nodata-with-setnull.htm)

Comment: Close. It sets the value to zero. Set_Null won't work because again, it's a form of raster analysis and will revert NoData back to 0. It's like that snake that eats itself.

Comment: No need to save intermediate raster results when working with spatial analyst. Keep them as variables, save final result. See help on any sa tool.

Comment: But where does the data for this variable go? It needs to be saved to disc or in_memory surely or it can't be used as a layer in further analysis? As I said, this is one process in a long line of processes hidden from the user. Can you expand on your answer? I don't think it's right. I have managed a workaround by creating a temporary workspace in USERPROFILE and deleting it, but it's not ideal. The ideal solution is to make in_memory preserve the raster extent.